# How do I change the look of my model fields on the front-end side?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

Ideally I want to "expand" my fields on the frontend. They have to be way longer just like when you make them from in the admin-panel. Currently they look like this:
[image]

However I want them portrayed like this (my admin is bootstrapped btw):
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">

<h1>Opret ny klient</h1>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Opret klient</button>
    <button type="button" class="save btn btn-default">Tilbage til klienter</button>
</form>

</div>
```

**The bottom line**
How do I make my form seem as visually appealing as it looks in my admin panel?

Comment: Use Bootstrap forms.- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for fast way, just use `crispy forms`
http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#installing-django-crispy-forms

`pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms`

in settings.py:
`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'crispy_forms',
)`

at the top of template:
`{% load crispy_forms_tags %}`
and render form like this `{% form|crispy %}`
it use `bootstrap` form by default

If you want more options to render your form, you can read docs about crispy. Or just use native django forms, and render each field of this form, like `{{ form.your_field }}`