# How to change form design in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Is it possible to change design of the `form` in `Django`? I've created a `form` which extends `UserCreationForm` because I want `user` to add more data.

It works correctly but it is very ugly. I've changed `form.as_p` to `form.as_ul` in my template and it helped a little but as you can see it is not the way it should be.

[image]

Let's say that I want for example put each label under it's input or put labels inside input windows like `facebook` does:
[image]

How could I do such things in `Django`?

My code:

**TEMPLATE:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_ul }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create the account">
    </form>
{% enblock %}
```

**FORM:**

```
class UserCreationFormExtended(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
```

Comment: You can control competely how your form widgets are displayed as per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: you can check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631980/how-do-i-change-the-look-of-my-model-fields-on-the-front-end-side/34632178#34632178

Comment: There are plenty of apps dealing with enhanced forms, search for crispy-forms and django-bootstrap3.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is something like this:

```
class UserCreationFormExtended(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
         widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), # or whatever class you want to apply
            # and so on
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Django has built-in libraries that can render your form based on your model.
However, it will definitely not suit your taste so you will need to add some styling using crispy tags.

I recommend you use the django-crispy-forms and style your form any way you want it. A reference to django-crispy-forms for bootstrap5 is found below.

https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5